# Table View with aggregation with 2 same field 1 with filter

Tags: views

I have a basic content type with date field and event type field. I am trying to create a view table like below

[image]

I created 1st two columns but cannot figure out how to create the 3rd column. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

This is Drupal 8. The code is as
    This is a Drupal 8 project. The code is:

`uuid: 589f89ad-2988-44b1-871e-83ee9104cbe2
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.node.field_event_type
    - node.type.application_form
  module:
    - node
    - options
    - user
id: event_view
label: 'Event View'
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: node_field_data
base_field: nid
core: 8.x
display:
  default:
    display_plugin: default
    id: default
    display_title: Master
    position: 0
    display_options:
      access:
        type: perm
        options:
          perm: 'access content'
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_comment: ''
          query_tags: {  }
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      pager:
        type: none
        options:
          offset: 0
      style:
        type: table
        options:
          grouping: {  }
          row_class: ''
          default_row_class: true
          override: true
          sticky: false
          caption: ''
          summary: ''
          description: ''
          columns:
            field_event_type: field_event_type
            field_event_type_1: field_event_type_1
          info:
            field_event_type:
              sortable: false
              default_sort_order: asc
              align: ''
              separator: ''
              empty_column: false
              responsive: ''
            field_event_type_1:
              sortable: false
              default_sort_order: asc
              align: ''
              separator: ''
              empty_column: false
              responsive: ''
          default: '-1'
          empty_table: false
      row:
        type: fields
      fields:
        field_event_type:
          id: field_event_type
          table: node__field_event_type
          field: field_event_type
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: 'Event Type'
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: list_default
          settings: {  }
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          plugin_id: field
        field_event_type_1:
          id: field_event_type_1
          table: node__field_event_type
          field: field_event_type
          relationship: none
          group_type: count
          admin_label: ''
          label: 'Event Type'
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: list_default
          settings: {  }
          group_column: entity_id
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          set_precision: false
          precision: 0
          decimal: .
          format_plural: 0
          format_plural_string: !!binary MQNAY291bnQ=
          prefix: ''
          suffix: ''
          plugin_id: field
      filters:
        status:
          value: '1'
          table: node_field_data
          field: status
          plugin_id: boolean
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: status
          id: status
          expose:
            operator: ''
          group: 1
        type:
          id: type
          table: node_field_data
          field: type
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: in
          value:
            application_form: application_form
          group: 1
          exposed: false
          expose:
            operator_id: ''
            label: ''
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: ''
            identifier: ''
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
            reduce: false
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: type
          plugin_id: bundle
      sorts: {  }
      title: 'Event View'
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      empty: {  }
      relationships: {  }
      arguments: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
      group_by: true
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: 0
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.node.field_event_type'
        - extensions
  block_1:
    display_plugin: block
    id: block_1
    display_title: Block
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: 0
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.node.field_event_type'
        - extensions`

Comment: Go to `admin/structure/views/view/your-views-name-here/export`, copy and paste the code here first.

Comment: This is a Drupal 8 project. I have added the code in the main question.